# jQuery - how to access jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to find out when to use #,$ in jquery.
i.e. if I have an object

```
var elem{
}
```

How to access this?
Whether $('#elem') or $('elem')?
May be its too silly. But I cant find out a solution by googling it.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using and how is your webapp set up in IIS? Non-aspnet extensions might be handled by IIS only so they skip global.asax (and the rest of the aspnet pipeline).

Comment: What's with the edit to completely change the question? If you have a new question then post it as a separate question. (You should change this one back so that the existing accepted answer actually makes sense.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like how to you've used `.appendTo()`. You need to pass an ID in your case, I believe; something like:

```
$("<table>").attr("id","waiterBlock").appendTo("testDiv");
```

*Changed to:*

```
$("<table>").attr("id","waiterBlock").appendTo("#testDiv");
```

[The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) for jQuery's `.appendTo()` says one needs to pass:

> A selector, element, HTML string, or jQuery object; the matched set of elements will be inserted at the end of the element(s) specified by this parameter.